# I can not access to the website with a public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am setting up a new EC2 with Ubuntu, but I am getting a weird error and it is that I can not access to the public ip, it says refused connection.

My security group has these ports enabled:

```
HTTP    TCP 80  0.0.0.0/0   -
HTTP    TCP 80  ::/0    -
SSH     TCP 22  0.0.0.0/0   -
SSH     TCP 22  ::/0    -
```

My public is: http://3.16.154.123/

The EC2 interface is running, it's in green and that is the public ip which it gives me... so I wonder what is the problem? why can I not access to the public ip? why does it say refused connection? or more clear this error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Thanks.

Comment: But ssh works, right?

Comment: @Marcin yes SSH works, I could enter

Comment: if you do `curl` your website from inside the instance, does it work properly?

Comment: Yes @Marcin SSH it's good etc, but port 80 not working and how you can see I have this port enabled What could it be? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`telnet 3.16.154.123 22
Trying 3.16.154.123...
Connected to 3.16.154.123.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
^]`

Your ssh is working as expected but on port 80 it fails.

`telnet 3.16.154.123 80
Trying 3.16.154.123...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

Can you check if there is any service running on the host itself using `telnet localhost 80` - If this works then it will be worth to check the NACL at the vpc level for any block on port 80.

Comment: When I put telnet localhost 80...... Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: and yes that is the problem connection refused.. I checked the VPC level if my ip was block, it does not have any IP blocked

Comment: seems like this is the issue. For the browser to display something there should be a service running on the host to acknowledge /serve that request. You need to run some service listening on port 80. `e.g. nginx`

Comment: @Vzla12345ooi I believe your question has been answered